# How to move 10 excel files to 10 different folders created by a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) which creates `10` different folders, e.g. `01`, `02`, `03` etc.

I also have `10` different Excel files ending with `_01`, `_02` etc.

Now I need a batch file to move `_01` excel file to `01` folder and rest of the files to folders.

Tried this to create N folders:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in (file.txt) do mkdir %%i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a plain `for` to loop over matching files. Then use a `for /f` to extract the number-part. Make a folder (`2>nul` suppresses the error message, should it already exist) and move the file:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*_*.xls) do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%n in ("%%~nf") do (
    md "%%n" 2>nul
    move "%%f" "%%n\"
  )
)
```